# How does Servlet HttpServletResponse::setCharacterEncoding() work?

Tags: servlets, character-encoding, httpresponse

I have learned that in general, Java uses UTF-16 as the internal String representation.
My question is what actually happens when composing a response in Java and applying different char encoding, e.g. `response.setCharacterEncoding("ISO-8859-1")`.

Does it actually convert the response's body bytes from *UTF-16* to *ISO-8859-1* or it just adds some metadata to the response object?

Comment: It would help if you could say exactly which class you're talking about.

Comment: @BalusC could you please explain why its not Java questoin?

Comment: This is a Servlet API question not a Java SE API question. Use [java] tag only for questions demonstrable with a plain Java application class with `main()` method and/or answerable with JLS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're talking about a class that works along the lines of `HttpServletResponse`. If that's the case, then yes, it changes the body of the response, if you call `getWriter`. The writer that is returned by that has to convert any strings that are written to it into bytes, and the encoding is used for that.

If you've set the content type, then setting the content encoding will *also* make that information available via the `Content-Type` header. As per the [`ServletResponse` docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#setCharacterEncoding-java.lang.String-):

> Calling setContentType(java.lang.String) with the String of `text/html` and calling this method with the String of `UTF-8` is equivalent with calling setContentType with the String of `text/html; charset=UTF-8`.

Comment: What did you mean by '**if** you call getWriter'?

Comment: @itamar: Well if you just call `getOutputStream` and write to that, the encoding won't affect the body of the response, only the headers.